# Filling a list inside a for loop in python

Tags: python, list

I am trying to  make a vector out of two different ones as shown in the piece of code below.
However, I get a list out of range exception on the 5th line the first time the code goes in the for loop.

What am I doing wrong?

```
def get_two_dimensional_vector(speeds, directions):
    vector = []
    for i in range(10):
        if (i % 2 == 0):
            vector[i/2][0] = speeds[i/2]
        else :
            vector[i/2 - 1/2][1] = directions[i/2 - 1/2]
```

Comment: Use [`enumerate`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#enumerate) in the loop

Comment: [i/2 - 1/2] in the final line should be replaced by [(i - 1)/2] for starters.

Comment: If it's integer division, you don't even need to do that. It will round down anyway.

Comment: The problem is that the OP uses a list of lists whereas the `vector` is only a list. That's why he gets the out of index error. I am not sure if the duplicated question has something to do with this one.

Comment: @Tasos: it will throw a list out of range error even before it has a chance to access the second dimension(index).

Answer (score 0):

You can't use a Python list this way. It's not like a C array with a
predefined length. If you want to add a new element, you have to use the
`append` method or something.

Aside from that, you're also using a second index, implying that the
elements of `vector` are themselves lists or dicts or something, before
they've even been assigned.

It looks like you want to convert `speeds` and `directions` to a
two-dimensional list. So, first, here's how to do that with a loop. Note
that I've removed the fixed-size assumption you were using, though the
code still assumes that `speeds` and `directions` are the same size.

```
def get_two_dimensional_vector(speeds, directions):
    vector = []
    for i in range(len(speeds)):
        vector.append([speeds[i], directions[i]])
    return vector

speeds = [1, 2, 3]
directions = [4, 5, 6]

v = get_two_dimensional_vector(speeds, directions)
print(v)
```

Now, the Pythonic way to do it.

```
print(zip(speeds, directions))
```